# Is it right way to use multi bucket in Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase

I can use option for Blaze so I added bucket in Firebase Storage.
At first, I couldn't use the added bucket but now I can use it the following way.

- I edited project_info for storage_bucket in google-services.json
  ex. "storage_bucket": "defualt" -> "storage_bucket": "added"
- then get the file location of firebase storage, it works.

But I'm not sure if it right or not 'cause I have to edit the configuration file.

Is there another solution for using the multi bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `google-services.json` only contains (as far as I know) information about the default bucket of your Firebase project. Modifying it to point to another can definitely work, but means you'll have to modify it each time you download the JSON file again.

The alternatively is to programmatically pass the bucket to `FirebaseStorage`, for example with this [`FirebaseStorage` constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)):

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://your bucket here");
```

Or by setting up a custom `FirebaseApp` instance with your configuration data, and then getting the storage service from that:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("1:27992087142:android:ce3b6448250083d1") // Required for Analytics.
    .setApiKey("AIzaSyADUe90ULnQDuGShD9W23RDP0xmeDc6Mvw") // Required for Auth.
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://myproject.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
    .setStorageBucket("gs://your bucket here")
    .build();
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options);

FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your expertise quick answer. It's definitely what I really wanted to know.